# Windows 8 Consumer Preview - Deleting Files

Tags: windows-8-preview

In Windows 8 Consumer Preview - when I press DELETE button on my keyboard for Deleting Files, it doesn't ask or prompt me to delete the file or not, it just delete the selected file without asking me.

Please let me know, how to turn that option on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this working on Windows 8 but it works in Win7 so worth a shot:

Right Click on the Recycle Bin -> `Properties`

Check the box that says `Display delete confirmation dialog`

Or if you prefer the registry:

Key: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

DWORD Value: `ConfirmFileDelete`

Value: `0`

Comment: Great, glad it worked :)